# Ability to create class instance with and without generics

Tags: c#

I have a question about generics in c# i want to create command class that can be called with generic type and without it something like:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;

    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    private readonly Action<TClass> tExecute;

    private readonly Predicate<TClass> tCanExecute;

    public Command(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public Command(Action<TClass> execute, Predicate<TClass> canExecute = null)
    {
        tExecute = execute;
        tCanExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || (this.canExecute != null && this.canExecute(parameter));
    }

    public bool CanExecute<TClass>(TClass parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || (canExecute != null && canExecute(parameter));
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute<TClass>(TClass parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

So i can use this this way:

```
new Command(p => some instructions);
```

or

```
new Command<Class> (p => some instructions p.property)
```

Problem is that class instance in this case always needs generic type in <>, and i know i can just cast p to certain type like (Class)p, but just wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not so much about creating generic instances - because you can always do that - but how will you manipulate commands uniformly. Will you be able to *use* the fact that one command is specific to some type *T*.

For this to work, you will at some point have to downcast something. I am not aware of any design which didn't have to downcast.

So, the process goes like sticking to the `ICommand` interface, which knows nothing about generics. Its `Execute` and `CanExecute` would be the only public interface available to all callers, and they would only receive an `object`.

```
interface ICommand
{
    bool CanExecute(object param);
    void Execute(object param);
}
```

Then, in the generic `Command<T>`, you could have strongly typed variants which are accepting `T`, and you would downcast `param`.

```
class Command<T> : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object param) =>
        this.CanExecute(param as T);

    public void Execute(object param) =>
        this.Execute(param as T);

    public bool CanExecute(T param) { ... }
    public void Execute(T param) { ... }
}
```

And that is where the troubles will begin for you. Can you guarantee that the parameter will be of the right type `T`, given an `ICommand` instance? If you can, then you're fine. Otherwise, you'll have a design flaw.

Note also that in this solution I am binding the `Command` class to a generic argument, not just one of its methods. If you only left `CanExecute` and `Execute` methods generic, then I expect huge issues later - such class would have too large field to cover. With generic commands, you are free to introduce an abstract `Command<T>` or an interface `ICommand<T>` and then construct special commands for some particular types `T`, like:

```
class SaveCommand : ICommand<Document> { }
class CreateDirectory : ICommand<DirectoryInfo> { }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make Command<T> class as base and redefine

```
class Command : Command<Object> {}
```

for using as non-generic.